# Selenium 2: Holding WebElements in cache after page has changed

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I want to be able to use WebElement instances after i moved to another page. I am not sure if that's possible, but there would be the need to store the current state of the browser window. Any pointers or ideas how to do this?

To go even one step further: I'd also like to use the object after the WebDriver instance was closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to get the info that you need from the webelement into other variables before moving to the next part of your test or killing the browser.

I would create a dictionary and then populate it with the webelement properties you want/need.

If you try use the webelement on another page you will get a `StaleElementReferenceException` thrown

Comment: That was my approach too. Hoped to get other ideas like simulating the current browser cache.

Answer (score 2):

There is also the **@CacheLookup** annotation you may use for WebElements, which is a:

> Marker annotation to be applied to WebElements to indicate that it never changes (that is, that the same instance in the DOM will always be used)